# How to remove the extra space between views in constraint layout?

Tags: android, dialog, android-constraintlayout

I have created a xml layout for dialog using constraint layout in android studio. There is some extra space below the buttons. No padding is set to views and bottom margin is also 0dp.There is white space remaining below the buttons. I want to align buttons to bottom of constraint layout with no white space. How to remove that space?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/alert_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/exit"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:cornerRadius="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cancel"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/alert_text" />

<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/cancel"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:cornerRadius="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/exit"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/exit"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/exit" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: What kind of view are you preparing? Please share image of it

Comment: What happens if you force the buttons to conform to the constraints you set, by setting their heights to 0dp instead of wrap_content?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `insetTop` and `insetBottom` to `0dp` in your `button` to remove extra space around button like below:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:id="@+id/exit"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="Exit"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:cornerRadius="0dp"

    android:insetTop="0dp"
    android:insetBottom="0dp"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cancel"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/alert_text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering there are no `marginBottom` attributes on the buttons, that gap is caused because of the button's actual background. There are 2 ways that you can solve this while still using a button:

1) Use a different background for each button (even if you use the not-elevated background there is still some margin on it)

2) Use negative margin on `android:layout_marginBottom` attribute. You can find the exact value with trial and error I believe.